# Compute all sublists with nth element removed

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a function `f` that, given a list of `n` elements, computes a list of `n` sublists of length `n-1`. Furthermore the nth sublist should contain all but the nth element of the original list. E.g:

```
f [1..4] == [[2,3,4], [1,3,4], [1,2,4], [1,2,3]]
```

I found a solution that seems to work, but it looks rather unintuitive:

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]]
f [] = []
f xs = reverse $ go (length xs - 1) xs
  where
    go 0 _  = [[]]
    go n xs = [ y:ys | y:xs' <- tails xs, ys <- go (n-1) xs' ]
```

Any suggestions for a more comprehensible solution with reasonable performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify a lot by observing that the homework problem contains a recursive structure that neatly matches recursion along the list itself.  If you pattern match on the input and it's non-empty, it has a first element of the list then the rest of the list.  The rest of the list neatly corresponds to the original list without the first element, so it should be the first output.  Then comes the recursion - getting the rest of the results is just a straight-forward application of `f` to the rest of the list and then fixing up the values so they're the right length and start with the right element.

Comment: I'd suggest taking out the "homework problem" remark. This is the better answer otherwise, IMO. [Works like a charm.](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hOlbBFkhwpSloVFhVFGsCeRXFClYKuYkFIBFNBY00oIDm/9zEzDygXEo@l4JCQVFmXomCigJQt6GenknsfwA)

Answer (score 8):

```
f xs = [ ys ++ zs | (ys, _ : zs) <- zip (inits xs) (tails xs) ]
```

`inits` and `tails` give you all prefixes and suffixes, in order (take a look at the result of `zip (inits xs) (tails xs)`). The list comprehension takes one element out of each non-empty suffix (`_ : zs`), and then concatenates the remaining elements together.

Comment: You could also `f xs = zipWith (++) (inits xs) (tail (tails xs))` to avoid needing the list comprehension. The scary partial `tail` is fine here, because `tails` is guaranteed to return a non-empty list.